# contains() method in java.util.HashSet doesn't behave as i expected from it

Tags: java, hashset

This is the java main() method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        HashSet set = new HashSet();
        Mapper test = new Mapper("asd", 0);
        set.add(test);
        
        System.out.println(new Mapper("asd", 0).equals(test));
        System.out.println(set.contains(new Mapper("asd", 0)));
        
    }
```

and my Mapper class is :

```
class Mapper {

String word;
Integer counter;

Mapper (String word, Integer counter) {
    
    this.word = word;
    this.counter = counter;
    
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    
    if ((o instanceof Mapper) && (((Mapper)o).word == this.word)) {
        
        return true;
        
    }
    
    return false;
    
}

}
```

and the result is :

> true
>
> false

From HashSet specifications, at this method I read this : "Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). "

So, can anyone explain me where i'm wrong? Or ...?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to add something, you should use the String `equals()` method (instead of the `==`, that's reference test) if you want to compare it's values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement a proper `hashCode()` function.

```
public int hashCode() {
  // equal items should return the same hashcode
}
```

The Java utilites `java.util` contain a lot of classes which rely on hashing.  To allow one to override `equals()` as they see fit means that one must also properly override `hashCode()` to match.

A correct implementation of `hashCode()` would return the same hash for any two objects where `equals()` returns true.  Hash related functions check the hashes for equality before checking to see if the objects equal (to resolve hash collisions).

Comment: ... and while you are at it, correct (or clearly document) your equals to not use referential equality for the string. In this case, you get away with it because "asd" is used twice in the same class file. But If you had read the string from user input, for example, the first comparison would have failed, too.

Comment: @Dilum : Why that? I know that strings are created in a string's pool of memory created apart when JVM is initialized.

Comment: @artaxerxe Strings are Objects.  The default implementation of hashCode() is to return a unique number for each instance.  If you create two strings ala `a1 = new String("a"); a2 = new String("a");` one would probably expect `a1 == a2` to be `false` as they are not the same object (due to the two new calls).  This means that for Strings (and other objects) `a1.equals(a2)` is typically much, much safer.

Comment: @artaxerxe What you said is only true of strings that are explicitly intern'ed. ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29 ). Lets say you read an XML document, and you get an element with attributes containing 'asd' and '0'. Those are not interned strings. That's one of countless cases where the string is not interned. Try this one to illustrate my point: System.out.println(new Mapper("asd".toUpperCase().toLowerCase(), 0).equals(test));

Answer (score 1):

The [hashCode contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) says that if two objects are equal, they should have the same hash code. Collections like `HashSet` assume that this is upheld.

`Object`'s implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` are based on addresses (or object IDs). If you override `equals` to do a content comparison, you should override `hashCode` to generate a hash based on content.